# How to divide download task between two application in android?

Tags: java, android

Suppose I have a file (URL available to download) and need to write code to split the download task between two different applications.First application process will download file from **start point** to **offset1** and next application process will download from **offset1** to **endpoint** of the file.  Last I need to merge the downloaded part? how can I proceed for such operation in android ?

Comment: Thats the requirement for your app. What is your issue occurred implementing that, you have to explain that issue. Then only anyone can help you.

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Why do you have two different applications? Do you mean two processes in the same app, or two completely different apps?

Comment: two completely different apps..! I just want to share my task(downloading task) with other people around me through the apps..

Comment: Problem I faced: suppose one large file is there in remote server (say 500MB capacity), now I need to write two different app(android) so that downloading task can be divided between two app. I know to write code for downloading any files in java.but how can I write a code to download a file from a particular portion(from a offset) of  a file to end as mentioned in the above questions. Hope I am able to explain you the actual problems.